# How to model this time-based relationship in Django? (images linked)

Tags: django, database-design

I'm having problems figuring out the best way to model the following relationship with Django.

I currently have a Site model as the main model that everything else attaches to. A Site is made of two basic building blocks: ModuleSlots and modules. A ModuleSlot is something that a module (which I'll describe in just a second) can be attached to.

Then I have a model called ModuleBase, which is the base model for modules that can be attached to site's moduleslots. A module is a self-contained piece of site that is itself functional – it doesn't know anything about the outside world. The ModuleBase model is meant to be inherited to create new modules – example modules are a Poll module and Content module. The point is, I want to have the ability to define new kinds of modules in the future, so that's why I went for the base-class approach. The picture below may better describe what I just wrote.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1nUw.png]

Now, I want to bring time into this scheme – ModuleSlot's content should be timeable, meaning that the module AND the attached poll/content/etc. should be able to change at the same, pre-defined time. For example, let's say that a ModuleSlot is currently tied to Content module. I want the ModuleSlot to change to point to a Poll module and show a spesific Poll. This all should happend automatically at spesific time.

How should I present this kind of relationship? I'be been giving this some though and this is what I have so far: I think I should create some kind of GenericContent model that is then inherited by individual content types that the modules define, eg. Poll of the PollModule would inherit from GenericContent, and Content of the ContentModule would do the same. I should also introduce TimeSpan for the ModuleSlot. Then, in the backend, I could check every minute if a ModuleSlot needs an update, and do the update if the module and attached content should be changed. What do you guys think? The messy picture below (may) describe the relationships described.

I'm not sure if the inheritance is the correct way to go here (GenericContent). I could also just store id of the Poll/Content/etc. in the ModuleSlot, as all my id's are the same type – since I know the module that is attached to a ModuleSlot, I can ask the Module for the content for the given id.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFE1h.png]